# Connecting to SalesForce from Web App

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

I was wondering if it is possible to connect to SalesForce from my web application in order to update a user's information. Let's say my customer has a user with a SalesForce ID of 123, and I have this same user in my application with an ID of 456. Is it possible to take the information I have on the user, connect to my customer's SF account, and update information on that user? Let's assume the user's email address is the same in both my customer's SF account and my own web app (or pretend some other custom identifier is known and is similar).

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce provides a [very extensive REST API](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/) which you could use to update the information within Salesforce as you describe above.

Your application could simply login using the API and update the items as needed to help in synchronizing the data, using the Salesforce query language SOQL to help retrieve the correct user as needed.

Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Paul

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for this. Seems like it's exactly what I need. If I understand this correctly, my application with login to SF with my customer's credentials via OAuth, then I'll search for the user that we have in common (let's say by email for now). Then using SOQL, I'll write up a query that will update the user's records in my customer's SF account.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. If you have a developer edition org you can login to it using the workbench at https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php to test out using the API.